# Python delete items from list to be added as column to list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing, compare

I have two sets of data. Both have a little over `13000` rows and, one of them (the one I open as a `csv` in the main function), has two columns that I need to match up to the other file (opened as text file and put into list of dictionaries in `example_05()` function).

They are from the same source and I need to make sure the data stays the same when I add the last two parameters for each row in the list of dicts because I have about 20 extra rows in the .csv file that I'm adding to the list of dicts so I must have extra or null data in the .csv file.

To delete these anomalous rows, I'm trying to compare the indices of the list of Q* values from the .csv file to the `{'Q*':}` value in the dictionary within the list of dictionaries (each dictionary is a row) to look for mismatches because they should be the same and then just delete the item from the mass_list before I add it to the list of dictionaries as I do at the end of `example_05()` function.

When I try to compare them I get an '`IndexError: list index out of range`' error at this line:

```
if row10['Q*'] != Q_list_2[check_index]:
```

Can anybody tell me why? Here's `example_05()` and the main function:

```
def example_05(filename):


    with open(filename,'r') as file : data = file.readlines()
    header, data = data[0].split(), data[1:] 

    #...... convert each line to a dict, using header words      keys   
    global kept 
    kept = []

    for line in data :
        line = [to_float(term) for term in line.split()]
        kept.append( dict( zip(header, line) ) )

    del mass_list[0]
    mass_list_2 = [to_float(j) for j in mass_list]

    del Q_list[0]
    Q_list_2 =  [to_float(k) for k in Q_list]

    print "Number in Q_list_2 list = "
    print len(Q_list_2) 

    check_index = 0 
    delete_index = 0   
    for row10 in kept:
        if row10['Q*'] != Q_list_2[check_index]:
            del mass_list_2[delete_index]
            del Q_list_2[delete_index]
            check_index+=1
            delete_index+=1
        else:
            check_index+=1
            delete_index+=1
            continue

    k_index=0
    for d in kept:
        d['log_10_m'] = mass_list_2[k_index]
        k_index+=1     

    print "Number in mass_list_2 list = "
    print len(mass_list_2)    


if __name__ == '__main__' :
    f = open('MagandMass20150401.csv')
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)

    mag_list = []
    mass_list = []
    Q_list = []

    for row in csv_f:
        mag_list.append(row[17])
        mass_list.append(row[18])
        Q_list.append(row[15])

    del csv_f    
    f.close()

    example_05('summ20150401.txt')
```

Comment: And also, I've tried using only check_index without the delete_index involved at all.

Comment: Any reason not to use csv.DictReader to read the data?

Comment: I'll look into it. But I want to delete the values in the mass data before I add it to the list of dicts

Comment: If this is a literal cut and paste of your code, then this line `kept.append( dict( zip(header, line) ) )` needs another level of indent. Otherwise, you will only append the final line of `data`

Comment: yes @kdopen that line is indented in my code alreay but I'll edit that on here.

Comment: have you tried it with some small sample files? Say 5 lines each. Also, staring at code hoping for inspiration sometimes works. Using ipython, enabling pdb, then examining all the variables when the exception fires, nearly always works :) At worst case, single step through the code with the smallest dataset that triggers the exception

Comment: Cut'n'paste error in the `for row10 in kept` loop? You increment both `check_index` and `delete_index` on every pass through the loop (i.e in both branches of the `if`, and the final `continue` is superfluous

Comment: Yes @kdopen haha I wish. I wrote the program testing it with a small set of sample data. Now I'm having to write on all these extra checking routines now that I'm using the actual data. Would anyone recommend reading and writing the files in binary since I have this many data points? This project is my second programming project ever so I don't know how much of a difference that would make.

Comment: Then pdb is your friend. Still curious about that loop, though. Without the data, no-ones going to be able to reproduce the problem. ... and please don't paste in two 13000 line files :)

Comment: Thanks though, I'll look into ipython. Never heard of that.

Comment: Somewhat more friendly version of the standard interpreter. It has tab completion, pretty printing, history, editing, any other goodies. Just 'pip install ipython' (hopefully in a virtual environment)